# How to avoid mixed up maven output?

Tags: java, maven, logging

In my maven build, if something goes wrong, maven randomly mixes it's own output the java log output and stack traces, which makes it hard to read. Is there a way to seperate this outputs in a better way?

Mixed output:

```
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_GRENZPUNKT ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_GRENZPUNKT_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_GRENZPUNKT_POSITION ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_GRENZPUNKT_POSITION_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_SYNONYM ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_SYNONYM_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_VIA ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_VIA_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_VIA_POSITION ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nReso[INFO]
urceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.BP_VIA_POSITION_P ok
[INFO] Results:
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.CODE ok
[INFO]
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.CODE_P ok
[WARNING] Tests run: 464, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DATEIABLAGE ok
[INFO]
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DATEIABLAGE_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DATENLIEFERANT ok
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DATENLIEFERANT_P ok
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIDOK_TU ok
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIDOK_TU_DATEN ok
[INFO] Total time:  45.664 s
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIDOK_TU_DATEN_P ok
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-26T11:53:14+01:00
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIDOK_TU_P ok
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIREKT_WAGEN ok
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apayye.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project zzzzz-common-utility: There are test failures.
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIREKT_WAGEN_LAUF ok
[ERROR]
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIREKT_WAGEN_LAUF_P ok
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\devxxx\projekte\zzzzz-all\zzzzz-cloud\zzzzz-common-utility\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DIREKT_WAGEN_P ok
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DURyyBINDUNG ok
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DURyyBINDUNG_P ok
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\devxxx\eaio-ng\jdk\jdk-11\bin\java -javaagent:C:\\devxxx\\eaio-n11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DWL_ANGEBOT ok
g\\m2\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.5\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\devxxx\\projekte\\zzzzz-all\\zzzzz-cloud\\zzzzz-common-utility\\target\\jacoco.exec -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\devxxx\softwar11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.DWL_ANGEBOT_P ok
e\cygwin64\tmp\surefire2206128093198867563\surefirebooter18404722970084311059.jar C:\devxxx\software\cygwin64\tmp\surefire2206128093198867563 2021-03-26T11-52-38_296-jvmRun1 surefire16349116801558469187tmp11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_AUFTRAG ok
 surefire_09362126464780780915tmp"
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_AUFTRAG_P ok
[11:52:43ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_KONF_KANTON ok
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_KONF_KANTON_P ok
[ERROR] yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_KONF_TU_GRUPPE ok
[ERROR] org.apayye.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without proper11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_KONF_TU_GRUPPE_P ok
ly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_KONFIGURATION ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.EXPORT_KONFIGURATION_P ok
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\devxxx\eaio-ng\jdk\jdk-11\bin\java -javaagent:C:\\devxxx\\eaio-ng\\m2\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.5\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\devxxx\\projekte\\zzzzz-all\\zzzzz-cloud\\zzzzz-common-utility\\target\\jacoco.exec -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\devxxx\software\cygwin64\tmp\surefire2206128093198867563\surefirebooter18404722970084311059.jar C:\devxxx\software\cygwin64\tmp\surefire2206128093198867563 2021-03-26T11-52-38_296-jvmRun1 suref11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FEIERTAG ok
ire16349116801558469187tmp surefire_09362126464780780915tmp"
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FEIERTAG_P ok
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FP ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FP_P ok
[ERROR] Crashed tests11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FPL_ZEIyyEN ok
:
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FPL_ZEIyyEN_P ok
[ERROR] yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FPS_KUNDENGLEIS ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:748)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FPS_KUNDENGLEIS_P ok
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FPS_LINIE ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.FPS_LINIE_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.GLEIS ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.GLEIS_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsyyecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.GLEIS_KORRESPONDENZ ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.GLEIS_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HAFAS_NETS_VM_NR_ZUORDNUNG ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HAFAS_NETS_VM_NR_ZUORDNUNG_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
11:52:43.775 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HALTECODE ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitT[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
est - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HALTECODE_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HALTEKANTE ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThr11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HALTEKANTE_P ok

eadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HAUPTLINIE_SLNID ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HINWEIS ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HINWEIS_P ok
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_ATTRIBUT_KORRESPONDENZ ok
[ERROR]         a11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_ATTRIBUT_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok
t11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_BAHNHOF_KORRESPONDENZ ok
 org.apayye.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_BAHNHOF_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_BETREIBER_KORRESPONDENZ ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMave11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_BETREIBER_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok n.java:105)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_BITFELD_KORRESPONDENZ ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_BITFELD_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_INFOTEXT_KORRESPONDENZ ok
[ERROR]         at org.apayye.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_INFOTEXT_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_TU_LINIE_FILTER ok
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_TU_LINIE_FILTER_P ok
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_TU_LINIE_INDEX ok
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_TU_LINIE_INDEX_P ok
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_ZUGART_KORRESPONDENZ ok
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launyyer.Launyyer.launyyEnhanced(Launyyer.java:282)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.HRDF_ZUGART_KORRESPONDENZ_P ok
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launyyer.Launyyer.launyy(Launyyer.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launyyer.Launyyer.mainWithExitCode(Launyyer.java:406)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.IMPORT_AUFTRAG ok
[ERROR11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.IMPORT_AUFTRAG_P ok
]       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launyyer.Launyyer.main(Launyyer.java:347)
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.IMPORT_DATEI ok
[ERROR]
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.IMPORT_DATEI_P ok
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.IMPORT_LIEFERUNG ok
[ERROR]
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.IMPORT_LIEFERUNG_P ok
[11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.INTERNER_AUFTRAG ok
ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven wi11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.INTERNER_AUFTRAG_P ok
th the -e swityy.
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.KOMPRIMIERUNGS_AUFTRAG ok
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X swityy to enable full debug logging.
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.KOMPRIMIERUNGS_AUFTRAG_P ok
[ERROR]
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.KURZ_NAME ok
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nResourceUnitTest - yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.MessageId.KURZ_NAME_NAyy ok
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apayye.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
11:52:43.776 [main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.I18nRes
ue73011@K57176 /cygdrive/c/devxxx/projekte/zzzzz-all/zzzzz-cloud/zzzzz-common-utility (feature/zzzzzLUSP-5783-verdiyytung-an-das-neue-db-modell-anpassen)
$
```

Comment: This `[main] DEBUG yy.xxx.zzzzz.common.utility.resource.` is part of your own logging and not Maven logging...

Comment: Yes of course. The question is how to avoid the mix up with the maven output.

Comment: Redirect your own output into an appropriate log file... usually configured by putting config file into `src/test/resources`...

Comment: Have you set up Surefire to run tests in parallel? Why would a testing thread continue after Maven reports the build fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with buffering of std/out and std/err stream.
If there is pretty much or they are printed very fast and the JVM did exit, this effect may happen. Waiting for JVM exit or empty buffer may be a deadlock. We have to find a way to fix it. Please report an issue in Jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE